# Why were some Launch Complex numbers skipped?

Tags: history, launch-site, cape-canaveral

The [Cape Caneveral Launch Complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cape_Canaveral_and_Merritt_Island_launch_sites) are numbered from 1 to 47, but curiously some numbers seem to have been skipped. The missing numbers are LC-7, LC-8, LC-23, LC-24, LC-27, LC-28, LC-33, LC-35, LC-38, LC-42 and LC-44.

Why is that? Where these sites planned but scrapped before being built?

Comment: The answer is very easy to be found using a good search machine on this [list](http://www.afspacemuseum.org/ccafs/) of all numbers from 1 to 47. Some like [44](http://www.afspacemuseum.org/ccafs/CX44/) were used long ago and only for a short time. Others like [23-24](http://www.afspacemuseum.org/ccafs/CX23-24/) were used for engine tests only. Some were never build [7-8](http://www.afspacemuseum.org/ccafs/CX7-8/).

Comment: No development plan survives contact with the real world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about all the launch complexes at this Air Force Space Museum page: http://afspacemuseum.org/ccafs/

The list is lengthy, but to sum up, as you surmised, some were planned and never built (for example, 7 & 8), others just no longer exist (for example, 44).