# When and why was Cape Canaveral "Launch Complex 40" renamed to "Space Launch Complex 40"?

Tags: launch-site, cape-canaveral, place-names, lc-40

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Space_Launch_Complex_40):

> Space Launch Complex 40 (SLC-40), previously Launch Complex 40 (LC-40)

It seems to me that all other Cape Canaveral launch complexes are just "LC" without the "Space" prefix, at least on common internet pages.

Wikipedia cites an archive of [Jonathan's Space Report from 1998 Feb 22](https://web.archive.org/web/20100503232748/http://planet4589.org/space/jsr/back/news.350):

> I now understand that the informal name change of the USAF operated pads
> at Cape Canaveral from LC (Launch Complex) to SLC (Space Launch Complex)
> was made official at some point during 1997, so I am adopting the change
> in my launch listings

- **When exactly in 1997 did this happen?**
- **Why was the name changed?**
- **Does the change apply to all complexes?** SLC-40 looks to have the most widespread use of the "Space" prefix.

Comment: Related: [Why were some Launch Complex numbers skipped?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25651/29286)

Comment: The west coast ones at Vandenburg were also SLC. "Slick-6" was supposed to be the Shuttle pad.